# How to reload WKWebView?

Tags: ios, wkwebview

Loading new content to `WKWebView` but content does not appear, old content remains. Any idea why?

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *c = [WKWebViewConfiguration new];
pdfView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero configuration:c];
pdfView.UIDelegate = self;
pdfView.navigationDelegate = self;
pdfView.scrollView.delegate = self;
[cell.contentView addSubview:pdfView];
[pdfView loadFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] allowingReadAccessToURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
[pdfView loadFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePathNEW] allowingReadAccessToURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePathNEW]];
```

Tried `reload()` does not work. Only recreating the whole `WKWebView`. But it does not efficient regarding memory usage.

Comment: Can you try pdfView.reload() ? Also I remember to add a different key on url as timestamp for esample myurl?somekey_with_randomvalue... This shall work.

Comment: Try to call pdfView.stopLoading() before new file loading.